# Zipping two lists of dictionaries

Tags: python, json

I'm new to Python and trying to create a new structure from json respones. The two json responses are tests that come from 2 environments but would have the same length and order, just different outcomes, for brevity I just simplified my example.

**response1.json**

```
[{"qa":"o"}, {"qa":"o"}]
```

**response2.json**

```
[{"prod":"x"}, {"prod": "x"}]
```

**create.py**

```
with open('response1.json') as data_file:    
    data1 = json.load(data_file)

with open('response2.json') as data_file:    
    data2 = json.load(data_file)

#i want to be able to create a structure like this:
# [{"qa":"o", "prod":"x"},{"qa":"o", "prod":"x"}]

list = []

#This is wrong but was thinking that logic would be close to this.
for i in range(0,len(data1)):
   list[i]['qa'] = data1[i]['qa']

for i in range(0,len(data2)):
   list[i]['prod'] = data[i]['prod']
```

Comment: I guess **respones1.json** is not valid JSON.

Comment: edited sorry about that

Comment: fixed sorry about that again

Comment: `list=[]` is a **very** bad statement: you destroy the built-in function `list()`.

Answer (score 1):

1) ***Python 3.5*** solution using `zip()` function and  dictionary unpacking operators `**`:

```
data1 = [{"qa":"o"},{"qa":"o"}]
data2 = [{"prod":"x"}, {"prod": "x"}]

new_struct = [{**x, **y} for x,y in zip(data1, data2)]
print(new_struct)
```

The output:

```
[{'qa': 'o', 'prod': 'x'}, {'qa': 'o', 'prod': 'x'}]
```

---

2) ***Python < 3.5*** solution using `dict.update()` method:

```
new_struct = []
for x,y in zip(data1, data2):
    x.update(y)
    new_struct.append(x)

print(new_struct) # will give the same output
```

Comment: Doesn't work in 3.4: syntax error at `[{**x`. (BTW, there is no need to call `list()`).

Comment: @DYZ, Can not agree with that.
`Python 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 25 2016, 22:18:55) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> data1 = [{"qa":"o"},{"qa":"o"}]
>>> data2 = [{"prod":"x"}, {"prod": "x"}]
>>>
>>> new_struct = [{**x, **y} for x,y in list(zip(data1, data2))]
>>> print(new_struct)
[{'qa': 'o', 'prod': 'x'}, {'qa': 'o', 'prod': 'x'}]
>>>`

Comment: Sorry, 3.4. >>> new_struct = [{**x, **y} for x,y in list(zip(data1, data2))]
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    new_struct = [{**x, **y} for x,y in list(zip(data1, data2))]
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @DYZ, removed redundant `list`

Answer (score 0):

```
json_list = [dict(list(x[0].items()) + list(x[1].items())) for x in zip(data1,data2)]
print(json_list)
```

Result:

```
[{'qa': 'o', 'prod': 'x'}, {'qa': 'o', 'prod': 'x'}]
```

Here's a more elegant but possibly less efficient solution:

```
json_list = [dict(sum([list(y.items()) for y in x], [])) 
             for x in zip(data1,data2)]
```

Comment: @linusg **NO** Do not overwrite the built-in list constructor!